# What does T $ \upharpoonright \alpha$ mean where T is a tree and \alpha is an ordinal?

Tags: set-theory

I am somewhat confused by this notation of what T $ \upharpoonright \alpha$ means for a tree T and an ordinal $\alpha$. Usually, I have thought of $ \upharpoonright$ as dealing with a function restricted to a subset of the domain, but T isn't necessarily a function. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks so much!

Comment: To restrict a function $f : X \to Y$ to a subset $S \subseteq X$, we write $f \mid_S$, not a hook.

Comment: @tylerc0816: In fact $f\upharpoonright S$ is an entirely standard notation for the restriction of $f$ to $S$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Hmm, I haven't seen that before.  Is that notation used primarily in one branch?

Comment: What's the context?

Comment: The context is dealing with Aronszajn's Theorem!

Comment: @tylerc0816: Not to my knowledge, though most of my reading is in set-theory and topology, so it’s possible. The first notation that I ever saw, many years ago, was $f|S$; I never encountered the version with $S$ downset as a subscript until quite recently (and I don’t like it, as I think that it’s unnecessarily hard to read).

Comment: @tylerc0816: That's kind of funny, because I recently talked to someone who'd never seen $|$ for restriction. I know the harpoon is reasonably common in NF studies since it was Quine's preferred notation, but I've seen it elsewhere. I think it's *Principia* notation.

Comment: Like Brian, I use the $\upharpoonright$ notation for restriction. I think vertical lines are already overworked as notations for absolute values and cardinalities. Also, I like to write the set $S$ full-size, rather than subscript-size, especially because it's often not just one letter but a longer expression and because in some discussions it is more important than $f$.

Comment: The answer may depend on the specific details of the construction you are studying. Sometimes we see trees as sets of functions, and sometimes we see them as sets of ordinals, equipped with a tree ordering. In the latter case, $T\upharpoonright\alpha$ is just $T\cap \alpha$ as a set.

Answer (score 4):

It generally means the subtree of $T$ consisting of those elements of $T$ whose heights are less than $\alpha$. If $T$ is of height $\alpha$, and you think of its elements as members of ${}^{<\alpha}A$ for some set $A$, then $T\upharpoonright\beta=\{t\in T:\operatorname{dom}(t)<\beta\}$.

Comment: I am not sure whether you have seen http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/7178/letting-less-reputable-people-answer-questions . This is exactly the sort of question that could be used to cultivate users with lower reputation

Comment: @Carl: I am more interested in providing the asker with a quick, correct answer when possible.

Comment: That is your choice, I suppose, but it is detrimental to the site overall for users who have earned enough rep to have all privileges to continue to take the low-hanging fruit. For that reason, I do not think this answer is useful to the site as a whole.

Comment: Also, it is worth emphasizing that a quick response can be left as a comment, so that someone else can write a longer answer later.

Comment: @Carl: And others complain when knowledgeable responders leave comments instead of answers. Take your vendetta somewhere else.

Comment: I'm not planning to make the same comment again, but I may vote in accordance with the position I explained.

Comment: @Carl: You may not be able to, at least where I’m concerned. I’m giving it $24$ hours, but this may just be the last straw that sends me on an indefinite sabbatical. I’m already fed to the teeth with the closure vigilantes.

Comment: @CarlMummert Down-voting answers because they don't follow a policy you think should be enforced is not called for. I'm sure Brian respects your stand on this idea (as I do) of "cultivating low rep users", but as he does, I disagree on you trying to impose it on others by these means. We once all were low rep users. Getting to the top depends on how much time and effort you put on this. Some users are here to ask questions solely, and no matter how much others try they won't start answering out of the blue (...)

Comment: (...) I do agree however that it is sometimes a downturn to have high rep users answer a question you also answered (as a low rep user) and see them get the most upvotes and praises. But they high rep. users usually have build a reputation (not only in the numbers) but in their useful contributions, big or small, complex or simple. Brian in particular doesn't discriminate simple or complex answers, and I think this is done not in the "give me rep" manner, but rather from a point of not discriminating the simple from the complex.

Comment: @Pedro Tamaroff: I appreciate your viewpoint. The key issue, I think, is that there are several different visions for the site. Of course, there is always a question of how forcefully one should promote his or her viewpoint. I hope it is sufficient to say that I came to the conclusion that my comment needed to be made only after considering it for some time.

Comment: @Brian M. Scott : Brian this is sometimes a consequence of being the number one in MSE. There is not such a thing as paradise. As for the problem itself. I strongly disagree with Carl Mummert  It is highly desirable that high-reputation users answer any kind of question, and also this is a pleasure for the asker to learn from an expert.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thank you for your time to answer and enlighten us with your way to tackle the math problems.

Comment: @DonAnselmo: You’re welcome.